# Which non-parametric two-sample SciPy test to use for my data?

Tags: python, nonparametric, continuous-data, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, scipy

I have three datasets. They contain the angles between a set of vectors (V1) and three other sets of vectors (V2,V3,V5). The datasets should all be continuous and non-parametric, I don't expect a certain distribution. I want to test if the distribution of the angles in each set is different than the other two sets (I assume I can do this two at a time). Specifically, I want to know if the overall shape is different between the distributions. I don't necessarily care if the means/medians are similar and, in fact, expect that to be the case. I think I have narrowed it down to the following tests within scipy.stats:

- mannwhitneyu (Mann-Whitney U)
- ranksums (Wilcoxon rank-sum)
- ks_2samp (Kolmogorov-Smirnov)
- epps_singleton_2samp (Epps-Singleton)

This is where I get stuck. If I understand correctly, and please correct me if I'm wrong, Mann-Whitney U and Wilcoxon rank-sum are more sensitive to changes in mean/median while Kolmogorov-Smirnov (KS) and Epps-Singleton (ES) are more sensitive to any differences in the two distributions. Thus, I believe I want KS or ES. Now, this is where I REALLY get stuck. What's the main difference between these two? KS seems to be pretty common, but I can't find a lot on ES. Also, if I'm way off on all of these, please, let me know. I don't have a strong background in statistics. Thanks so much in advance for any advice.

Bonus question: What does it mean if a KS test on two datasets is not significant but a ES test on the same datasets is significant?

Here are the distributions I'm talking about in violin plots if that's at all helpful.
[image]

Comment: I suggest that your question will be improved and of interest to more people (to answer or read) if you de-emphasize the scipy aspect. It doesn't seem relevant that there is a scipy implementation of them.

Comment: The Mann-Whitney U and Wilcoxon rank sum tests are usually the same test.  They are not necessarily sensitive to differences in the mean or median, but instead to the likelihood that an observation in one group is greater than an observation in the other group.